# How to describe the state of an n-state system?

Tags: single-word-requests

Often I need to use a generic description to explain a system that has multiple states.

For instance if I am explaining that a message can be urgent or non-urgent, I could  say:

> Message priority (urgent or non-urgent) is given to messages based on it's *urgencyness*.

This is a trite example, because we have a word for this, and it is 'urgency'.

> Message priority is given to messages based on it's urgency.

However there are scenarios where there isn't an adjective, or we need to highlight multiple states.

For example, if an action can have a state of 'emergency' or 'non-emergency':

> Action priority is given to an action based on it's emergency*ness*.

Here the word *emergency* doesn't work, and adding 'ness' to the end does not seem formally correct (it should be however easy to understand).

I have taken in some cases to (ab)using the word parity:

> MATHEMATICS
>   (of a number) the fact of being even or odd.

As a shorthand to explain something, albeit clumsily.

> Action priority is given to an action based on it's emergency parity.

This falls down in cases where there are multiple states an object can be in, e.g. Old, Recent, New.

Is there a single word that can be used to explain a non-trivial system, with fixed states, without listing them:

> Emails are coloured based on their Age _______

Comment: Emails are coloured based on their age.  Action priority is *assigned* based on *its* urgency.   (emergency seems to be on a continuum of urgency- more urgent than urgent)  which is really just: Action priority is assigned based on its deadline.

Comment: @Jim this is a [tag:single-word-request] looking to cover a word for all of those (and more unstated) examples.

Comment: I think my point was that to assign something, you must measure something and then see where that measurement falls on the scale.  You can say something is urgent or not but you are implicitly saying its deadline is near or far.  Perhaps by looking at what is *measured* you can find the specific word to use in each case.

Comment: @jim Do I have to edit in more examples to show that just reusing one of the words doesn't every time?

Comment: No, that’s clear I think. My point is:  Heat Level: (Hot, Cold, Freezing)  Effectiveness: (Extreme, moderate, somewhat, none)  Volume: (Loud, moderate, soft, faint)  what is measured? For heat level: Temperature.  For Effectiveness: Time to respond. For Volume: sound pressure level. Etc.  Therefore: Heat level is assigned based on temperature.  Effectiveness is assigned based on time to respond. Volume is assigned based on sound pressure level.  Action priority is assigned based on time before deadline.  Some things are trivial: Height (Tall, Medium, Short) is assigned based on ... Height.

Comment: Your category answer doesn’t really give any new information about how those categories were selected.  “People are assigned based on their eye category” doesn’t really help. But assigned based on their eye color, or based on their visual acuity, does.

Comment: @Jim but not all of those have a single word to describe them. What about hair? "Stylists will be assigned based on our three different Hair ___" Type? Categories...?

Comment: Hair *styles*??

Comment: @jim I'm looking for a ***single word*** to describe the above an innumerable others. If I had only asked for one of any of these your suggestions would have been perfect. But I'm not.

Comment: What are you measuring to determine the hair category? “straightness”? “color”? “length”?  Or which style they are asking for?

Comment: @jim you're getting bogged down in the specifics of the examples. It doesn't matter (to me) what determines the categories.

Comment: I’m saying you may be on a wild goose chase, and you’d be better off using a specific word for each case. Afterall, it seems like you only started down the “single word” path when it seemed like there wasn’t a specifc word available in each instance.  But I think there must be in all cases if you change the way you’re looking. :-)

Comment: @jim I think I just need better examples which may take time to come up with. Please bear with me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In explaining this question well enough to post it, I have come across a word that fits my needs:

> ### category
>
> #### /ˈkatəɡ(ə)ri/
>
> *noun* noun: category; plural noun: categories
>   1. a class or division of people or things regarded as having particular shared characteristics.
>   *"the various categories of research"*

The given sentences become:

> Action priority is given to an action based on it's emergency category
>
> Emails are coloured based on their age category

Comment: but 'age' and 'emergency' *are* the categories.  What you want is the *value* or *degree*.

Comment: @AmI but 'Emergency Value' and 'Emergency Degree' don't scan as well to me.

Comment: Similar to *category* is *classification*.